# Graphviz executables not found. Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, graphviz

I`m trying to get this code to run:

Getting started with Graphviz and Python
http://matthiaseisen.com/articles/graphviz/

```
import graphviz as gv

g1 = gv.Graph(format='svg')
g1.node('A')
g1.node('B')
g1.edge('A', 'B')

print(g1.source)
```

this part works fine, but...

```
filename = g1.render(filename='img/g1')
print (filename)
```

-> make sure the Graphviz executables are on your systems' PATH

I found similar questions/answers, but I don`t know much about the Windows registry, so I don`t dare to experiment a lot there. I downloaded Graphviz as zip-file, and I did conda install graphviz at some point. Python 3.6 is installed per default. C:\Users\Oliver\Appdata\Local\Programs\Python36.

I go to Control Panel - System - Advanced System - Environment Variables, but what exactly do I have to change there?

Answer (score 1):

I could finally solve this:

The graphviz zip I had direcly extracted directly in my Downloads-folder (or wherever you want to have it).

Control Panel - System - Advanced System - Environment Variables

Then in the lower half, System Variables (not User variables), double-klick Path: klick `New` and browse to the graphviz bin-folder.